# How to deduce the size of C∩B from the sizes of A, B, C, A∩C, A∩B and A∩B∩C?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The original question was:

A small school with 16 students has a cricket team with 11 players, a netball team with 7
players, and a chess team with 4 players.  Each student is on at least one of these teams and
no student is on all three teams.  There is exactly 1 student who plays cricket and chess and
exactly 2 who play cricket and netball.  How many students play chess and netball?

This is how I attempted it:

Let **A** be the students who play cricket. **Pr(A)** = 11/16   [Pr represents propability]

Let **B** be studnets who play net ball. **Pr(B)** = 7/16

Let **C** be students who play chess. **Pr(C)** = 1/4

**A∩C** = 1 or **Pr(A∩C)** = 1/16, **A∩B** = 2 or **Pr(A∩B)** = 1/8, **A∩B∩C** = 0 or **Pr(A∩B∩C)** = 0

I have to find C∩B or Pr(C∩B). I can do this if I can break down Pr(A∩B∩C) but I do not know how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is "you cannot". You need an additional piece of information. Try drawing a Venn diagram.

Comment: What information do I need?

Comment: I think the OP has enough information in the problem statement. So the problem is perfectly solvable.

Comment: Yes, if you look at peter.petrov's answer, you can see that if you also know $|A\cup B\cup C|$, which apparently you do, then you can get $|B\cap C|$.

Comment: Would A∪B∪C be 16 in this case? I am confused as to whether that is the sample space value of the value for the unions for all A,B and C

Comment: Since it is stated that "each student is on atleast one of these teams" i guess A∪B∪C = 16

Comment: Why are you using probabilities?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) principle here.

Just apply this formula and you should get the answer.

$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |B \cap C| - |C \cap A| + |A \cap B \cap C|$

Comment: "more to come"? Seriously? Why don't you just write a full answer and *then* submit it?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, seriously...

Comment: In that case is A∪B∪C = 16? Or is the entire sample 16?

Comment: Yes, I think it's 16 (from the problem statement).

Comment: Because If I don't know A∪B∪C the inclusion-exclusion principle won't help me

Answer (score 1):

> A small school with 16 students

$$|\text{Universe}| = 16$$

> has a cricket team with 11 players,

$$|A| = 11$$

> a netball team with 7 players,

$$|B| = 7$$

> and a chess team with 4 players.

$$|C| = 4$$

Each student is on at least one of these teams

$$|A \cup B \cup C| = 16$$

> and no student is on all three teams.

$$|A \cap B \cap C| = 0$$

> There is exactly 1 student who plays cricket and chess

$$|A \cap C| =  1$$

> and exactly 2 who play cricket and netball.

$$|A \cap B| = 2$$

> How many students play chess and netball?

$$|B \cap C| = ?$$

Use inclusion exclusion as the other answer indicated.